# Creating a wordpress page template with editable sections

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a page template that has different editable sections - as in this question - [How do I create different editable sections within a wordpress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628888/how-do-i-create-different-editable-sections-within-a-wordpress-page)

But the answer that I'd like to follow has a link to a non existent page - http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#File_Folders

I'd really like to create a template that displays the content of other pages as sections, as the Twentyseventeen front page does (but on another page)

Could someone post a link to that info, or advise me here?

Thanks

Vik

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's the page that you're looking for: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

> Page templates display your site’s dynamic content on a page, e.g., posts, news updates, calendar events, media files, etc. You may decide that you want your homepage to look a specific way, that is quite different to other parts of your site. Or, you may want to display a featured image that links to a post on one part of the page, have a list of latest posts elsewhere, and use a custom navigation. You can use page templates to achieve these things.

Comment: Thanks - but I've read that page, and it doesn't seem to explain how to have different sections that display the content of other pages... like in the twentyseventeen home page setup

Comment: Are you a developer? If yes you can do it simply by writing some PHP WordPress codes inside of your custom page template.

Comment: Thanks @hossein. I'm a beginner and trying to learn. Do you know what codes I would write into my template file to call the content of another page by its id?

Comment: You may use this code
`$post_7 = get_post( 7 ); 
$title = $post_7->post_title;`
It's for getting the post data by id.

Comment: And would I replace 7 with the id of the page?

Comment: Yes, sure! You should change it to your desired post's ID.

Comment: Pasting that into my template just makes the code appear on the page